# Google drive api web_content_link and web_view_link always nil | Rails

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

First of all, I use Google Service account for this. I successfully get a file and information about it, but when I try to web_content_link or web_view_link it's always nil.
Here is my code

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v3'
require 'googleauth'

credentials_file = Rails.root.join('config', 'google_drive_credentials.json')
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.authorization = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open(credentials_file),
  scope: scope
)

GOOGLE_DRIVE_SERVICE = service
```

Controller code

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @drive = GOOGLE_DRIVE_SERVICE
    @files_list = GOOGLE_DRIVE_SERVICE.list_files
  end
end
```

Views code

```
<h1>Files on Google Drive</h1>
<% @files_list.files.each do |file| %>
 <p>
    <%# binding.pry %>
    <%= file.name %>
    <%= file.id %>
    <%= file.mime_type %>
    <%= file.web_view_link %>
    <%# link_to 'Download',  %>
    <%# @drive.get_file(file.id)  %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Service accounts cant access the google drive web app so i wouldn't think they could have a webview link. that and the file type would need to be a drive mimetype.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo thx for the answers. Is there a build-in way to download files from service account without specify mime_type for each file?

Comment: you need to know the mime type to determine if you need to do an export or can just download the file directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
service.get_file(@exact_file, fields: 'web_view_link').web_view_link
```

where

```
service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.authorization = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open(credentials_file),
  scope: scope
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).